# Coldfusion 10 - Error: Calling LoadLibraryEx on ISAPI filter isapi_redirect.dll failed

Tags: coldfusion, coldfusion-10

I am working with a fresh install of CF10 on a Windows Server 2008R2 machine.

I am getting the following error:

```
HTTP Error 500.0 - Internal Server Error

Calling LoadLibraryEx on ISAPI filter "C:\ColdFusion10\config\wsconfig\1\isapi_redirect.dll" failed


Detailed Error Information



Module

IIS Web Core



Notification

Unknown



Handler

StaticFile



Error Code

0x80070005





Requested URL

https://127.0.0.1:443/cfide/administrator/



Physical Path

C:\ColdFusion10\cfusion\wwwroot\CFIDE\administrator\



Logon Method

Not yet determined



Logon User

Not yet determined
```

Can anyone point me in a direction on how to fix this? I have followed installed and uninstalled the connectors several times using wsconfig with no success.

Comment: More a question for ServerFault than here.

Answer (score 0):

I had to actually reboot the entire server for wsconfig updates to take effect.